# Is there an iPhone UI component equivalent to the Cocoa NSColorPicker API?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm looking for a way to allow the user of my iPhone application to select a color for marking items. I know I could just use a standard picker with the color text names but if something already exist like the NSColorPicker API in Cocoa, I'd rather use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to make your own using sliders.